# Why do the cells in table view duplicate when user clicks on accept button?

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an app in which a user can send a friend request to an another user, and the user who receives a request can either accept it or delete it. It's working as intended. However, when a user clicks on accept button, the cells of tableView(which shows received requests) duplicates. And when I reload the table view or restarts the app, it shows desired results, that is, only showing pending requests. Also, data gets stored on firebase database as intended. Only concern is the spontaneity and error behind duplicating cells initially. Also, how can I customize cells, such that whenever the user clicks on accept or delete button, only that cell gets dimmed, then removed from the table?

EDIT:

I have tried using viewDidLoad in place of viewDidAppear too!

Code for received request function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    receivedFunc()

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ReceivedViewController.receivedFunc), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    receivedTable.addSubview(refresher)

}

func receivedFunc() {

    //

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    refHandle = ref.child("users").child(currentUserID!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {

            if let requests = userDict["requests"] as? [String: String] {

                print("processing requests")

                self.userIDs.removeAll()
                self.userNames.removeAll()
                self.userImages.removeAll()

                for request in requests {

                    if request.value == "received" {

                        self.refHandle = self.ref.child("users").child(request.key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                            if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {

                                if let userName = userDict["name"] {

                                    let storage = Storage.storage()

                                    let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://money-owelend.appspot.com")

                                    let profilePhotoRef = storageRef.child(request.key + "profile_photo.jpg")

                                    profilePhotoRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in

                                        if let error = error {

                                            print("couldn't download the image")

                                        } else {

                                            self.userNames.append(userName as! String)
                                            self.userIDs.append(request.key)
                                            self.userImages.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)

                                            //
                                            self.receivedTable.reloadData()
                                            self.refresher.endRefreshing()

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }, withCancel: { (error) in

                            print("error observing value \(error)")

                        })

                    }
                }

                // reload data here

            }
        }
    }, withCancel: { (error) in

        print("error observing value \(error)")

    })

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return userIDs.count

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellReceived", for: indexPath) as! ReceivedTableViewCell

    cell.hiddenIDLabel.text = userIDs[indexPath.row]

    cell.userName.text = userNames[indexPath.row]

    cell.userImage.image = userImages[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
```

And Finally, code for cells:

```
  @IBAction func acceptButton(_ sender: Any) {

    // add the user to current user's friend list

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    let currentUserRef = ref.child("users").child(currentUserID!)

    currentUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.hasChild("friends"){

            self.ref.child("users").child(self.currentUserID!).child("friends").updateChildValues([self.hiddenIDLabel.text!: "true"])

        } else{

            self.ref.child("users").child(self.currentUserID!).child("friends").setValue([self.hiddenIDLabel.text!: "true"])
        }

        print("user successfully added as a friend to current user's list")

    })

    // remove this request from user's received requests

    let currentUserDeleteRef = ref.child("users").child(currentUserID!)

    currentUserDeleteRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.ref.child("users").child(self.currentUserID!).child("requests").child(self.hiddenIDLabel.text!).removeValue()

    })

    // add the current user to the user's friend list

    let senderRef = ref.child("users").child(hiddenIDLabel.text!)

    senderRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.hasChild("friends"){

            self.ref.child("users").child(self.hiddenIDLabel.text!).child("friends").updateChildValues([self.currentUserID!: "true"])

        } else{

            self.ref.child("users").child(self.hiddenIDLabel.text!).child("friends").setValue([self.currentUserID!: "true"])
        }

        print("user successfully added as a friend to sender's list")

    })

    // remove this request from sender's sent requests

    let senderDeleteRef = ref.child("users").child(hiddenIDLabel.text!)

    senderDeleteRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.ref.child("users").child(self.hiddenIDLabel.text!).child("requests").child(self.currentUserID!).removeValue()

    })

}
```

[My firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRlDW.png)

Comment: @Kinushuk Singh please post minimal code related to your issue.It gets difficult to check entire code.

Comment: @TusharSharma I have removed some of the code. But I don't know where the error might be. That's why posted wherever possible!

Comment: you can use breakpoint and test your code,and reach the point of crash.

Comment: That's the problem! My app is working as intented. No crashes or whatsoever. Just initial replicating of requests as soon as user taps on accept button making me sick!

Comment: Sing you mean when you scroll you see duplicate right ?

Comment: It's like, whenever the user taps on accept button, the user becomes friends with the sender and data gets updated on the firebase in real-time. However, table cells in received requests table duplicates.

Comment: sorry mate not much good with firebase yet.Hopefully anyone else will help you out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the friends adding system smooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907135/how-to-make-the-friends-adding-system-smooth)

Comment: You seems to be asking several questions and you show a huge amount of code. Please [edit] th equestion to make your real question clear. Also remove the code that is not relevant to the real question. Many people find that creating an [mcve] help them to find the answer themselves.

Comment: @ChristopherSmit that question was also asked by me, but the objective of both questions are quite different. I will delete my old question.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I have edited my question to make it shorter